# Is there a way to build a site column and implement it twice(or more) in the same list?

Tags: list, site-column

I want to create a list of names in and Offices site column and then use this around my site. Specifically I want to have a list with columns called OPR and OCR, but they need to be from the same site column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You would need to create a separate site column.  SharePoint doesn't support adding multiple instances of the same site column.

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought too. I was hoping I was missing something. So there are no workarounds. I just don't want to have to update multiple columns when there is a change.

Comment: If it's a "choice" type column, and you're not on Foundation, you could look into using  managed metadata columns. The two columns could be set to pick from the same set of terms.

Comment: Yea, I'd just create multiple Site Columns.  You still have one place to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem -

I ended up adding the columns by code and used the fields. I used AddLookup Method : 
You need to provide the web id where the site column is defined and the list id 
of the source list of the site column.

Call AddLookup multiple times with different Display names and you
get a list with multiple lookup all referencing to the same Lookup
(or to the same Site Column).